# How to fire multiple onKey events when swiping on Android custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I managed to create a new Input Method of my own following the guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Everything's working alright, but one thing I would like the keyboard to behave is when user press the Q key and swipe all the way to Y, it should type out 'qwerty'.. what do we need to set to achieve this?

Currently onKey only receives the last key event when you lift up the finger, which is Y in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your own View and Handle the touch events. For example you can implement the above behavior like this:

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView{

    int downKeyCode = -1;  

    private int getKeycode(int x, int y){
        int index = -1;
        List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Keyboard.Key k:keys){
            if((x>=k.x && x<=k.x+ k.width) && (y>=k.y && y<=k.y + k.height))
                return k.codes[0]; 
        }
        return index;
   }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        int x = (int)me.getX();
        int y = (int)me.getY();
        int action = me.getAction();
        int currKeyCode = getKeycode(x, y);
        switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downKeyCode = currKeyCode;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(downKeyCode == 'q'){
                if(currKeyCode == 'y')
                {
                    // type "qwerty"
                    downKeyCode = -1; 
                    return true;
                }   
            }
            downKeyCode = -1; 
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(me);
}
```

}